# How to rewrite one image with another in IIS using URLRewrite

Tags: iis, url-rewriting, web-config

Here is my problem, I need to rewrite one image with another (don't ask why).
Simple URLRewrite rule is not working.

Every time someone fetch this URL: http://example.com/images/001.jpg
IIS should show 002.jpg (http://example.com/images/002.jpg)

web.config:

```
<rules>
    <rule name="img1" stopProcessing="true">
       <match url="images/001.jpg" />
       <action type="Rewrite" url="images/002.jpg" appendQueryString="false" />
    </rule>
</rules>
```

Comment: Did you try to use `Redirect` instead of `Rewrite`? And FRT can tell you more about what IIS does under the hood, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/using-failed-request-tracing-to-trace-rewrite-rules

Comment: redirect & rewrite didn't work

Comment: Then you need to edit the question to include FRT logs.

Comment: It looks like rewrite works and cache was the problem, after starting Chrome in incognito mode i works. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tested your URL rewrite rule and it works normally on my side.

So please try to clear your browser’s cache and try again.

And do you get any errors? If not, you can only use FRT to view detailed messages.

Comment: After watching FRT logs as Lex Li mentions, just starting chrome in incognito mode shows rewrite image.

Comment: I'm so glad that the problem has been resolved. It is so appreciated if you can mark your solution as answer.